# Translation in different language

Tags: translation

I have an application with different languages.I have translated the word **Logout ** in spanish language.The translation for **Logout** in spanish is **Cerrar sesión**.But when it is translated it gives **Cerrar sesi�n**.please Help.How can i overcome from this. It gives **�** when any spanish word have some sign upon the letter.

Comment: it looks like strange german. in the picture it is german with malfomed umlauts.

Comment: You want to display alert in different language right? did you initialize alert in all language what you want ?

Comment: sorry wrong image attached.now it is corrected.

Comment: i had just translated the message from google translator and it gives me Sind Sie sicher, dass Sie löschen möchten? as dutch translation.

Comment: Still looks like German, though.

Comment: Google returns "Weet u zeker dat u wilt verwijderen" as Dutch for me.

Comment: ok its mistake by me in hurry....now it is perfectly changed.

Comment: now there is no problem anymore ...

Answer (score 1):

this is encoding problem, check if all the files or resources are saved or served as UTF-8 and if utf-8 encoding is defined in the page

Answer (score 0):

Define alerts you want in Several language like this,

```
alert_indiff_language = { 
               "english" : "Are you sure you want to delete?", 
               "Dutch" : "Sind Sie sicher, dass Sie löschen möchten?" 
}

your_function() {
    alert(alert_indiff_language[language])
}
```